# CSS column grid issue with sorting

Tags: css

Inspired by this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/), I've set up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/2zND2/) that has 5 columns. That works fine with 5 images. With 6, however, it sorts it into [2 rows of 3](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/2zND2/1/) instead of one row of 5 and a row of 1. Other configurations have a similar effect.

Is there a reason for this and a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Also that css property `width: 100% !important;` is differently interpreted in IE9 and in other browsers. Btw, if you want IE8 compatible page, don't use column gap, but float it as in the answer below.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I approach any use of CSS3 with some scepticism, if only because of issues with old school browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use as an additional style, like this:

```
   float:left;
```

Comment: This shouldn't be needed at all.

Comment: @Stano Nice job, but you made a few more edits than just the float: left; if you post it as a separate answer, I can give you  complete credit.

Comment: While yes this works, this does not actually fix the columns issue.

Comment: @Loktar Not sure what you mean, but imho [this simple floated solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2zND2/2/) gives the same result and fixes the column issue. If you know a better way how to fix it, you are welcome to publish your solution here. Or you can send your suggestion to w3c, maybe they will create some new parameter for column-count property to modify this behaviour. Good luck

Comment: @Stano yeah basically I'm pointing out this doesn't actually fix, or address the quirkiness with the css3 `columns`. Its a work around using a completely different method.

Comment: I think the point is that the css3 column spec leaves it up to the browser to build the columns _based on the content provided_. By not specifying a column width, `column-count` only serves as a [maximum](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#cc) value. Columns and rows are two deferent entities. When I read the OP's question, it almost appears to me that it's focused more on the rows than the columns, which begs the question why fiddle (pun intended) with css3 columns to begin with. A while back I created an [app](https://www.box.com/s/laecbkd565i7h6jemi2s) based on this premise alone.